# Splash screen wont destoy itself? Java

Tags: android, splash-screen, onpause

At first my splash screen works perfectly, however later I tried to put in a code which would destroy the activity splash. I did this by putting the onPause method into the end of the protected void.

This is the splash screen before putting in the method

```
'package com.shipment.emulatorfix;

'import android.app.Activity;
'import android.content.Intent;
'import android.media.MediaPlayer;
'import android.os.Bundle;

'public class Splash extends Activity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openMain = new Intent("android.intent.action.TESTINGEMULATORACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openMain);
            }
        }
    };
timer.start();
}



'}
```

this is the after code

```
'package com.shipment.emulatorfix;

'import android.app.Activity;
'import android.content.Intent;
'import android.media.MediaPlayer;
'import android.os.Bundle;

'public class Splash extends Activity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openMain = new Intent("android.intent.action.TESTINGEMULATORACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openMain);
            }
        }
    };
timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

'}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: put  finish(); in the finally block.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

protected int _splashTime = 2000;   
private Thread splashTread;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);        

    splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {                   
                synchronized(this) {
                    wait(_splashTime);
                }                   
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("EXc=" + e);
            } 
            finally {              

                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class ));                 
                //stop();
                finish();
            }
        }
    };      
    splashTread.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but that did not do anything. Also it did not start the splash with that code

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Welcome extends Activity
{
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Handler mHandler,actHandler;          

   @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
     setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

    new Thread(){
       public void run(){
       try{                
          Thread.sleep(3000);                 
          }                               
       catch(Exception ex){

          Log.e("Welcome Exception :",ex.toString());
          }
              try{
                 Message msg=mHandler.obtainMessage();  
                 mHandler.sendMessage(msg);     
                 }
                 catch(NullPointerException ex){
                 Log.e("Handler Exception :",ex.toString());                                                         
                }                       
              }

    }.start(); 
      mHandler=new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
        super.handleMessage(msg);                


        Intent i=new Intent(Welcome.this,M_chat.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        }
        };  
      }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finish the activity and then start the other activity.

```
Thread timer = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        try{
            sleep(5000);
        } catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            finish();
            Intent openMain = new Intent("android.intent.action.TESTINGEMULATORACTIVITY");
            startActivity(openMain);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(5000);
            } catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent openMain = new  Intent("android.intent.action.TESTINGEMULATORACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openMain);
                Splash.this.finish();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```